# pandas compare two dataframe and count equal keyword

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my sentence 'sentence' datafrme
(It is just sample. Data is so big.)

```
sentence = pd.DataFrame({'sentence':['I like to go to starbucks', 'I do not like coffee', 'how can i sign in instagram', 'gift']})
```

[image]

'db_keyword' dataframe

```
db_keyword = pd.DataFrame({'lv1':['event', 'event', 'event', 'gift', 'gift'],
                         'lv2':['event', 'starbucks', 'instagram', 'gift', 'voucher'],
                         })
```

db_keyword

[image]

I wnant this result, how can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
out = (db_keyword.groupby('lv1')
       .agg(lambda x: sentence['sentence'].str.count('|'.join(x)).sum())
       .reset_index())
```

`out`

```
    lv1     lv2
0   event   2
1   gift    1
```